# How to slow down a typography effect in after effects?

Tags: after-effects

I'm using Adobe After Effects 2014 and I have got a royalty-free template of a typography effect. And it's really fast, I want to increase the duration of the effect(when the text is in focus in the video so I can give it a bit more reading time) without distorting it by like slowing the whole video down. How can I do that?

Comment: you need to include more information. is it keyframed? is it using an animator? is it using expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is a template applied to a text layer in a comp, select the text layer and press "u" to reveal any keyframes on that layer.  Drag the keyframes out to the duration you need.

If the comp isn't long enough, press Command K to reveal the comp settings, extend the duration.  Extend the duration of the text layer by dragging the end of it further to the right.